# MySQL Replication - how to clear master status on a slave

Tags: mysql, database, database-replication, master-slave

I have been migrating our databases, because they were growing too large for the old server. To do this, I had set up Master-Slave Replication, so we were running both the old and new servers during the transition period.

There are three database servers:

`A --> B --> C`

Where A is the old server, B is the new production server and C is the backup server. 
A is a master, B is slave to A and a master, and C is a slave to B.

I want to remove the database from A (as above, it's getting too big for the server), and so have stopped the slave on B using `STOP SLAVE`. I can also clear B's position in A's binary log files using `RESET SLAVE`.

However, if I do `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` on B, it still shows A as being the master.

How do I clear the master on B? 
Is there an option with `CHANGE MASTER TO` that I am unaware of?
Is there an alternative command?

I have looked through the MySQL replication docs and cannot any such [sql statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-slave-sql.html).

Comment: You may want to post this in http://dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Look for a [master.info](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-slave.html)  file.

Answer (score 1):

Try it.

Stop slave; 
reset slave;
reset slave all;

it will remove master from slave.